# Akka Persistence Query and actor sharding

Tags: akka, cqrs, akka-stream, akka-cluster, akka-persistence

I'm doing the query side of a CQRS Akka actors app.

Query actors are setup as a cluster shard and are filled in with events from one Persistence Query stream.

My questions are:

1. If one of the actors in cluster shard restart how to recover it?

   - Shut down the whole cluster shard and reply all the events?
   - Make the actors in cluster shard persistent actors and save new set of events for query side only?
2. If the actor which is filler with Persistence Query restarts, how can I cancel current PQ and start it again?

Comment: Are you keeping the state of the query actors only in memory? For my query side I use Persistence Queries to update a database view.

Comment: Yes, I'm only keeping the state in memory in actor.

Comment: Are your views only consuming one persitence id or more?

Comment: For example BookingSaved event will be persisted and then ApartmentAvailableActor will use it and BookedPeriodsActor will use it as well. So every query actor will consume only one persistenceId, for now :)

Comment: That doesn't look like one persistentId to me. Assuming that Bookings are an aggregate on your command side, each booking should have its own persistenceId. So if ApartmentAvailableActor consumes all BookingSaved events, then it consumes different persistenceIds

Comment: Aside from that, why are you using one persistence query for the whole shard?

Comment: I was thinking about the persistenceId from the actor that persisted the event.

Comment: I would use sharding because that would simplify my state in the actor. I can create a new actor for every new booking and create a state machine. And for prices I can easily segragate prices from specific userID-unitID compound key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116408/discussion-between-reeebuuk-and-thwiegan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed I would evaluate persisting your query side in a database.

If that is not an option and you want to stick with your single persistence query per shard do the following in your query actor:

```
var inRecovery: Boolean = true;

override def preStart( ) = {
    //Subscribe to your event live stream now, so you don't miss anything during recovery
    // e.g. send Subscription message to your persistence query actor

    //Re-Read everything up to now for recovery
    readJournal.currentEventsByPersistenceId("persistenceId")
        .watchTermination()((_, f) => f pipeTo self) // Send Done to self after recovery is finished
        .map(Replay.apply) // Mark your replay messages
        .runWith( Sink.actorRef( self, tag ) ) // Send all replay events to self
}

override def receive = {
    case Done => // Recovery is finished
        inRecovery = false
        unstashAll() // unstash all normal messages received during recovery

    case Replay( payload ) =>
        //handle replayed messages

    case events: Event =>
        //handle normal events from your persistence query
        inRecovery match {
            case true => stash() // stash normal messages until recovery is done
            case false => 
                // recovery is done, start handling normal events
        }
}


case class Replay( payload: AnyRef )
```

So basically before the actor starts subscribe to the persistence query actor and recover the state with a finite stream of all past events, which terminates after all events have passed through. During recovery stash all incoming events, which are not replayed events. Then after recovery is done, unstash everything and start handling the normal messages.